# Sliding BasicTextField characters

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

If you use BasicTextField as a space to write your password and write your password longer than it appears,
BasicTextField moves to the next space and then the letters are written. What I want is to make it so that if I write longer than it appears, the letters will be pushed out and the letters will be written.

```kotlin
BasicTextField(value = password,
        onValueChange = {
            if (it.length <= passwordMaxCharacterCount) {
                password = it
                passwordOnValueChange(it)
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(50.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 30.dp, end = 30.dp)
            .onFocusChanged {
                isFocused.value = it.isFocused
            }

            .background(AuthEditTextColor, shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 13.dp)),
        visualTransformation = if (checkStatus) VisualTransformation.None
        else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
        textStyle = authText.bodyMedium,
        maxLines = 1,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password),
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 30.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                if (password.isEmpty() && !isFocused.value)
                    Text(text = hint, style = authText.bodySmall)
                Box(modifier = Modifier.width(100.dp)){
                    innerTextField()
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                PasswordStatusCheckBox(checkStatus) {
                    checkEvent(it)
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: For example, if you type a long password on Instagram and write longer than what is visible, the text will be pushed to the left and the text will appear.

Comment: So if there is space for four visible letters, you mean it should look like this while typing? `[ABCD]` `[BCDE]` `[CDEF]` `[DEFG]`

Comment: Yes, please tell me how to implement it like that in Compose BaseTextField.

Comment: I think the `BasicTextField` should behave like you want by default. Can you try how it is currently behaving in your case?

Comment: I come out as [ABCD] [EFGH]